# Writing a semaphore using a monitor

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, ipc, semaphore, monitor

I'm having this excercise, which I don't know how to solve it:

> Build semaphores using monitors: please define variables val (the
>   semaphore value) and Qu (of type condition), on which would be
>   possible suspending that process that if calling qWait() finds val =
>   0. Implement it and qSignal(), defining the code that initializes the semaphore as well.

I came up with this :

```
monitor Semaphore {
   integer val;
   condition Qu;     //value > 0

   procedure qWait() {
      val--;
      if (val < 0)
         Qu.wait();
   }

   procedure qSignal() {
      val++;
         Qu.signal();
   }

   Semaphore(int init) {
      val = init;
   }
}
```

do you think it's the right solution?

Comment: Consider asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I don't think this is a code review issue; this is a matter of I need some help, and the poster has shown what s?he has tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the programming language you are writing this in.  If I can assume that only one thread of execution can be actively executing within the *monitor* at a time, then I think your implementation is sufficient.  If that is not the case, then you need some extra code to handle this.

Using a *simple* language, like C, can help to clarify the requirements.  To implement a semaphore (or a monitor) would require a mutex and a condition variable, like so:

```
struct Sem {
    int value;
    mutex lock;
    condvar cond;
};
int qsignal(struct Sem *s) {
    Lock(&s->lock);
    if (++(s->val) <= 0) {
       Signal(&s->cond);
    }
    Unlock(&s->lock);
    return 0;
}
int qwait(struct Sem *s) {
    Lock(&s->lock);
    if (s->val-- <= 0) {
        Wait(&s->cond, &s->lock);
    }
    Unlock(&s->lock);
}
```

Notice here that both functions are bracketed in a lock which prevents the Sem structure from changing while this is executing.   The Wait() function atomically releases the lock and blocks the caller until the cond is Signaled().  Once signaled, it re-acquires the lock (waiting if necessary), and continues.

You can see the structural similarity to your code; but the lock transitions are more explicit.   I hope this helps!